# Can somebody explain to me why the 2 and -2(theta) were removed in this summation shown below?

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot figure out why the 2 and -2(theta) were removed in the attached image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Formula Attached]

> $\frac{d}{d\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\theta^2(1+y_i))^2=
> \sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\theta^2(1+y_i))(-2\theta(1+y_i))$ and set $=0$. So
>   $\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\theta^2(1+y_i))((1+y_i))=0$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i(1+y_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n \theta^2(1+y_i)^2=0$.

Comment: It would be useful to type the question properly. (Even if it is deemed off-topic here and you decide post it on another site.) Some basic advice can be found here: [How does one type mathematical formulas on this site?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3763) To help you get started, I have retyped the formula from your picture.

Comment: Adding some more details could be useful. (Where does this derivation come from? What is it that you're actually try to optimize? And so on.) You can check the FAQ post "[How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)" - especially the [part about context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 3):

You put 
$\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\theta^2(1+y_i))(-2\theta(1+y_i)) = 0$

The $2$ and $-2\theta$ are constant factors in front of every summand. So you can also move them before the sum sign.

$2(-2\theta)\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\theta^2(1+y_i))((1+y_i)) = 0$

And hence you can remove it, if you want to know when your sum is equal 0.